# Connection Error only on Youtube

Tags: proxy, youtube, chromium

I am getting a **"Connection Not Private"/NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID** error only when accessing Youtube. I have tried 4 different browsers (Brave, Chrome, Vivaldi, Edge) and this error occurs on all of them. Curiously, while trying to use Psiphon VPN, it tells me that *Psiphon was unable to set proxy*. This only happens on my laptop. My phone on the same network is able to access Youtube just fine.

I have no proxies set up and I am using the default settings in the IPv4 settings. Please help me fix this error.

[image]

EDIT: Tried the solutions given [here](https://appuals.com/fix-err_cert_common_name_invalid-connection-not-private/) and clearing cache. None of them worked. It's not a browser specific issue.

Comment: A Google search for the error message led me to e.g. https://appuals.com/fix-err_cert_common_name_invalid-connection-not-private/

Comment: @Bodo Tried these. Still not fixed.

Comment: Then please [edit] your question and tell what you already tried.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers store certificates in cache. Have you tried clearing the cache for YouTube?

Here is a solution targeted at Chrome browser: https://serverfault.com/a/688828/594921

Comment: Tried deleting cache. Didn't work.